# Why is electric field constant over the charged solid Gaussian sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law

I saw this example at griffiths. It’s a basic question about gauss’s law but I saw the electric field being treated as a constant and thus, it got outside of the integral. I couldn’t quite understand this.

Comment: Is there spherical symmetry in the distribution of charge?  To use Gauss's Law efficiently, you should identify symmetries in the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the charge carriers are not prevented  from moving in the material of the sphere (e.g. they are mobile charge carriers in a conducting solid sphere), the charges will distribute themselves uniformly so that at equilibrium the electric field is zero anywhere within the sphere. In other words, a uniform distribution insures an electrostatic condition in the conducting material.

Hope this helps

Comment: I see I get it now. Sorry for such a simple question

Comment: @user244918 no problem. Glad it helped

Comment: @user244918 Why don't you accept Bob D's answer, if you are satisfied ?

Comment: I’m new to this site, forgot to accept, sorry.

Comment: @user244918 no problem. It happens a lot with new contributors